# How to save model of MLP in Theano using python?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, deep-learning, theano

I want to save model I get after training in MLP using theano.

Here is the code:

```
def test_mlp(learning_rate=0.01, L1_reg=0.00, L2_reg=0.0001, n_epochs=500,
         dataset='mnist.pkl.gz', batch_size=20, n_hidden=500):

datasets = load_data(dataset)
...
######################
# BUILD ACTUAL MODEL #
######################
 # construct the MLP class
classifier = MLP(
    rng=rng,
    input=x,
    n_in=28 * 28,
    n_hidden=n_hidden,
    n_out=10
)
...
cost = cost = (
    classifier.negative_log_likelihood(y)
    + L1_reg * classifier.L1
    + L2_reg * classifier.L2_sqr
)
test_model = theano.function(...)
validate_model = theano.function(...)
train_model = theano.function(...)


###############
# TRAIN MODEL #
###############
...
best_validation_loss = numpy.inf
best_iter = 0
test_score = 0.
epoch = 0
done_looping = False

while (epoch < n_epochs) and (not done_looping):
            # after several processing I get the outputs as:

            validation_loss = numpy.mean(validation_losses)
            best_iter = iter
            test_score = numpy.mean(test_losses)
```

after this I need to save the model as:

```
            # save the best model
            with open('best_model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(classifier, f)
```

but it leads to an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 471, in <module>
    test_mlp()
  line 404, in test_mlp
    pickle.dump(classifier, f)
  File "/Users/X/anaconda/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

I checked it on logistic regression model and it was saving my model and I was able to load it again. But here it has this problem. Do you know why this happens? what is the solution?

Comment: Better way is to only pickle weights because that's what you need at prediction time, so why not only pickle weight parameters i.e `pickle.dump(classifier.params, f)`.
Add weights to MLP constructor, initialize randomly if they are `None` else initialize it to passed params.
Something like here (example is for RNN but you can apply the same trick)
https://github.com/uyaseen/theano-recurrence/blob/master/model/rnn.py

Comment: yes . and thanks. I solved it with your suggestion.